# Restructuring XML using xslt displays only text

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having a xml file as input to the xsl file. When i am specifying the outputmethod of xsl as xml and defining an element using xsl:element or matching an element from the xml as said in the other threads i am not getting any tags.I am getting only the text of the xml.I have tried various examples. Whatever i tried i am getting only the text part of the xml. Can you give me a simple example that contains full working code of transforming one xml into another xml using xsl.

Sorry for not posting the sample.

I tried restructuring of xml in two ways:

1) Having an xsl and xml file in the same folder and opening the xml using the browser.The xsl file is applied to the xml as below.

**test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl"?>
<root>
<info>
    <firstname>Bob</firstname>
    <lastname>Joe</lastname>
</info>
<notes>
    <note>text1</note>
    <note>text2</note>
</notes>
<othernotes>
    <note>text3</note>
    <note>text4</note>
</othernotes>
</root>
```

**sample.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root">
   <root>
     <xsl:copy-of select="info"/>
     <notes>
        <xsl:copy-of select="othernotes"/>
     </notes>
   </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**
Bob Joe text3 text4

Both the files are in the same folder and i opened the xml file using the browser to see the output.

2)In am using struts framework with xslt in my project. The xml set to the view is as follows.
**XML:**

```
<root>
<data>
<array-list>
<array-list xsi:type="java:java.util.ArrayList">
<slot-info-object avail-crit-thresh="-1.0" avail-fif-min="-1.0" avail-five-min="-1.0" avail-one-day="0.0" avail-one-hr="-1.0" avail-warn-thresh="-1.0" freeslot="0" keyn-service-subtype-id="9" perf-crit-thresh="-1.0" perf-fif-min="-1.0" perf-five-min="-1.0" perf-one-day="0.0" perf-one-hr="-1.0" perf-warn-thresh="-1.0" severity-type="0" shared-script-id="-1" slot-id="671457" trans-id="733299" user-id="0" xsi:type="java:com.keynote.mykeynote.service.dashboard.SlotInfoObject">
<slot-alias>Single slot</slot-alias>
</slot-info-object>
<slot-info-object avail-crit-thresh="-1.0" avail-fif-min="1.0" avail-five-min="1.0" avail-one-day="1.0" avail-one-hr="1.0" avail-warn-thresh="-1.0" freeslot="0" keyn-service-subtype-id="9" perf-crit-thresh="-1.0" perf-fif-min="0.5105" perf-five-min="0.529" perf-one-day="0.6195208333333333" perf-one-hr="0.5505" perf-warn-thresh="-1.0" severity-type="0" shared-script-id="595" slot-id="685397" trans-id="-7105" user-id="0">
<slot-alias>SharedSlot</slot-alias>
</slot-info-object>
</array-list>
</array-list>
</data>
</root>
```

The view is the xsl file that contains the following code:
**XSL File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root/data/array-list/array-list">
<root>
<slot-info-object>
     <xsl:for-each select="slot-info-object">
     <xsl:copy-of select="slot-alias"/>     
     </xsl:for-each>
</slot-info-object>
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output:**
Single slotSharedSlot

One more Question:
request.setAttribute(StrutsCXConstants.XML_KEY, data); 
Here data is the java collection like ArrayList. THis line is written in the struts Action file.This is only converted to the xml for the view.
When we are saying this in the xsl

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

should the response type in the Struts Action class must be set to "text/xml"

Thanks.

Comment: We could help if you a) Provided an .xml input, b) provided your current .xslt or sample of it.

Comment: Can you show us input XML (or an extract), the stylesheet and the resulting output (or extract)? We'll need at least the stylesheet to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Whatever I am doing it is only raining. Can you give me a simple example that contains a fully working implementation of sunny weather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my second case, I got the text because i didn't set the response type to xml in my java action class. Once I set that, the xsl displays my own custom tags and the tags in the xml which i sent to the xsl.

Regarding my first case, as Dimitre Novatchev said we have to use some command like the one given in the following link.
http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/199912/msg00082.html

Thanks all for ur info.

Answer (score 4):

The chances are this is caused by the fact that none of your template rules match anything in the source, and the chances are that this is caused by the fact that your XML is in a namespace. There - I've debugged your stylesheet without seeing a single line of code, I hope you are impressed. Just think how much easier it would be if you showed us your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**:

What you see in the browser is what the browser displays when presented with non-HTML.

**Solution**:

One of the following:

1. Save the output in a file (don't use the browser to perform the transformation, but invoke it in another way -- say from the command-line), then view this file with a normal text editor.
2. Add in your XSLT code HTML elements that would cause the browser to display whatever you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL code doesn't have a template for the root node "/" so there is no starting point for the generation of nested tags. If you change your template element to

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
```

then  you will see some output.